# Getting error FutureTask@2c7b84de rejected when using threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

Here is my code:

```
class Processor implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    private Integer interaction;
    private Set<Integer> subset;
    private static volatile AtomicBoolean notRemoved = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public Object<E> dcp;
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator;



    public Processor(int id, Integer interaction, Set<Integer> subset, Object<E> dcp, Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
        this.id = id;
        this.interaction = interaction;
        this.subset= subset;
        this.dcp = dcp;
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (Processor.notRemoved.get()){
            System.out.println("Starting: " + this.id);
            if (this.dcp.PA.contains(this.interaction)){
                this.subset.add(this.interaction);
                this.dcp.increaseScore(this.subset);
                if (!this.subset.contains(this.interaction) && Processor.notRemoved.get()){
                    Processor.notRemoved.set(false);
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Completed: " + this.id);
        }   
    }
}


public class ConcurrentApp {

    public void mainFunction (Object<E> dcp, int threads) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

        int i =1;
        while ((dcp.PA.size() > i) && (i <= dcp.R)){
            for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = dcp.PA.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                Integer interaction = iterator.next();
                ArrayList<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<Integer>(dcp.PA);
                removed.remove(interaction);
                ArrayList<Set<Integer>> subsets = dcp.getSubsets(removed, i);
                for (int j = 0; j< subsets.size(); j++){
                    executor.submit(new Processor(j, interaction, subsets.get(j), dcp, iterator));
                }
                executor.shutdown();
                System.out.println("All tasks submitted");
                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("HERE");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("All tasks completed");
            i++;
        }   
    }
}
```

When I run mainFunction in ConcurrentApp, I get the following error:
*Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2c7b84de rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3fee733d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 8]*

I know this is because I'm not using *executor.shutdown()* correctly but I'm not sure why?

**EDIT:** I print when each thread starts and completes its task. Here is the console output:

```
Starting: 1
Starting: 2
All tasks submitted
Starting: 0
Completed: 2
Completed: 1
Completed: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2c7b84de rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3fee733d[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 8]
```

This at least shows that the 3 threads in the thread pool complete their task before the error goes off.

Comment: "volatile AtomicBoolean" is not necessary. Use one or the other

Comment: @efekctive OH YEAH! thanks for the catch. I forgot AtomicBoolean is already volatile.

Comment: would you try the following: switch submit for execute?

Comment: No luck, I get the same exact error :/

Comment: I am stuck right now. But I would check that the active count == 0 before calling shutdown

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your time. How would I do that?

Comment: tpe getActiveCount()

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the problem here! It was simply because I was calling executor.shutdown() within the while loop before all the tasks were completed. So the new code is:

```
    public void multiRemoveParents (DirectCausalPredictor<BayesianScoresNew> dcp, int threads) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);

        int i =1;
        while ((dcp.PA.size() > i) && (i <= dcp.R)){
            for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = dcp.PA.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                Integer interaction = iterator.next();
                ArrayList<Integer> removed = new ArrayList<Integer>(dcp.PA);
                removed.remove(interaction);
                ArrayList<Set<Integer>> subsets = dcp.getSubsets(removed, i);
                for (int j = 0; j< subsets.size(); j++){
                    try {
                        executor.submit(new Processor(j, interaction, subsets.get(j), dcp, iterator));
                    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e){
                        System.out.println("Task was rejected");
                    }   
                }
            }
            System.out.println("All tasks completed");
            i++;
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("All tasks submitted");
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was my exact problem